# Quarkus Reactive REST Client: How do I poll an endpoint every second with a timeout of 10 seconds?

Tags: quarkus, mutiny

I have a Quarkus app with health checking enabled running in a container on port 9000. I can make a health request to that app from another Quarkus app (call it app2) as shown below. It returns the health json. All good.

I am using docker-java to create and run the container on port 9000 and I want to know as soon as it is ready so I can start accessing it via Quarkus reactive rest client from app2. So, I want to poll it every second until I get the health check back and status UP (and some other "withData"). If, after 10 seconds I don't get the health json (and/or status is not "UP"), it should fail and return a "timeout" message.

What is the best approach for a Uni pipeline to do that kind of polling?

My proxy:

```java
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;

@Path("/q/health")
@ClientHeaderParam(name = "Content-Type", value = "application/json")  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface OrgHealthProxy {
  @GET
  Uni<JsonObject> GETAsUni();
}
```

The single call that works as long as the container is up and running:

```java
return orgHealthProxy.GETAsUni()
    .onItem()
    .transform(orgHealthJsonObject -> {
      Log.info("getHealthDataFromOrgContainer Received response =" + orgHealthJsonObject.toString());

      // eg {"status":"UP","checks":[....]}
      // Get the overall status string UP DOWN
      String status = orgHealthJsonObject.getString("status");

      if (status.equals("UP")) {
        // Maybe modify the JsonObject ...
        // Then return the JsonObject
        return orgHealthJsonObject;
      } else {
        String errMsg = "ERROR: the container is not ready. Status=" + status;
        throw new Error(errMsg);
      }
    })    
    .onFailure().recoverWithItem(.... // Try call again somehow?);
```

So, how do I extend the Uni pipeline above to handle the polling and cope with failures like container not running yet (maybe died on docker run, or just too early), health checks not finished yet, etc?

Thanks,
Murray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with Mutiny like this:

```
return orgHealthProxy.GETAsUni()
            .onItem().invoke(s -> System.out.println("Trying " + s))
            .onFailure().invoke(throwable -> System.out.println("Failed " + throwable))
            .onFailure().retry()
            .withBackOff(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .atMost(9);
```

`atMost(9)` retries means 10 together invocations with the original one.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! Works great. :-)
I wonder whether there is a "Mutiny Cookbook" in the works that lists the Mutiny approach to this kind of common pattern? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just a fine tune to the answer from @xstefank for this "health check" use-case.

When the target app / container is not yet accepting requests, the onFailure() returns `io.vertx.core.http.HttpClosedException: Connection was closed`.

Once the target app is accepting requests, if the health status is "DOWN", the REST request onFailure() returns `'Service Unavailable, status code 503' when invoking: Rest Client method: 'com.flowt.central.gateway.OrgHealthProxy#GETAsUni'`. All good, except I was expecting a status 200 with the health json and thought I would need to check for `"status": "DOWN"`. It turns out it doesn't work that way - ie we get a 503 instead.

Also, the `.onFailure().retry().withBackOff(Duration.ofSeconds(1))` gets longer and longer between retries.

**EDIT:** I posted a more complete solution here: [Quarkus discussion 32202](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/discussions/32202)

So, I found this works better for my use-case:

```java
.onFailure().invoke(throwable -> Log.info("REST request failed because: " + throwable))
.onFailure().retry()

// Use this form so the period between checks doesn't grow. ie Always 500ms
.withBackOff(Duration.ofMillis(500), Duration.ofMillis(500))

// Keep trying for 8 seconds...
.expireIn(8000);

// ... instead of using this option
//.atMost(19);
```

And in 8 seconds you get:
`AuthGateway.createUserAndOrg failed because: Retries exhausted : 16 attempts against 1679967601548/1679967601105 expiration`

Mutiny is awesome, once you know how!

Thanks again,
Murray